# Glue connection not working through cloudformation. It is giving error : Unable to resolve any valid connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

My glue connection created through cloudformation is not working whereas if create a glue connection with same configuration through the console it works perfectly fine.
Please find the code for the same :

```
Resources:
Policy1:
Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
Properties: 
  Description: Policy for glue
  PolicyDocument: 
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action: '*'
      Resource: '*'
Role1:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
DependsOn: Policy1
Properties: 
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
    - Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        Service:
          - glue.amazonaws.com
          - rds.amazonaws.com
      Action:
        - 'sts:AssumeRole'
  ManagedPolicyArns: 
      - !Ref Policy1
GlueConnection:
Type: AWS::Glue::Connection
Properties: 
  CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
  ConnectionInput: 
    ConnectionProperties: 
      JDBC_CONNECTION_URL: "jdbc:mysql://database-2.cxs4adwnjt5i.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/mydb"
      USERNAME: "admin"
      PASSWORD: "Admin123"
      JDBC_ENFORCE_SSL: False
    ConnectionType: JDBC
    PhysicalConnectionRequirements: 
      SecurityGroupIdList: 
        - sg-065781f0ee39344fa
      SubnetId: subnet-0cdac25848264fdb8
    Name: rds-1
GlueDatabase:
Type: AWS::Glue::Database
Properties: 
  CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
  DatabaseInput: 
    Name: my-rds-glue-1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this you need to include AvailabilityZone in PhysicalConnectionRequirements.

```
PhysicalConnectionRequirements:
  AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs  '' ] 
  SecurityGroupIdList: 
    - !Ref GlueSG
  SubnetId: !Ref  SubnetId
```

See more details here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-connection-physicalconnectionrequirements.html

Until this gets fix the workaround is, like you mentioned, to go in the console and just edit and save the connection.

Comment: Yes, adding az in the code did the trick.

Comment: JSON: `"AvailabilityZone":{"Fn::Select":[0,{"Fn::GetAZs":""}]}`

Comment: So, according to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-connection-physicalconnectionrequirements.html#cfn-glue-connection-physicalconnectionrequirements-availabilityzone) it is redundant and `Required: No`. But in reality it is still required or else it fails with a message that doesn't make the problem clear.